# Removing gray part of BBEdit/TextWrangler

Tags: text-editor

How can I remove the gray part in BBEdit/TextWrangler.
I want it to be white as the other part.

Screenshot (see part marked with red square):

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is called the *page guide*. You can hide it in TextWrangler in two ways:

1. For a single document, select "Hide Page Guide" from the "View -> Text Display" Menu.

   [image: Screenshot of the Text Display menu]
2. To hide it for all documents, there is a setting in the "Text Status Display" category.

   [image: Screenshot of the Text Status Display preferences]